# How to compare two instants in Java?

Tags: java

**I want comparison two `Instant`s to see if equals both or greater than**, but i can’t.
i dont know. how i can compare instants?

```
  private Instant expiration;

 if(expiration()==Instant.now()||expiration()>Instant.now())
  {
     valid+="the Expire date is invalid check it . ";
  }
```

i  try this way but i have compile error.
but i think cant comparison in this way
it  must change instant to String and compare after it
but i dont know how to format to string

Comment: You might have compile errors because you added parenthesis after `expiration`, but expiration in your example is a variable, not a method. So if you remove those, you should at least be able to get rid of the compile errors.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't convert them to Strings.  Instant, like every other `Comparable` type, has the `compareTo` method.  Use it like this:

```
if (expiration.compareTo(Instant.now()) >= 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `Instant` also has more semantically meaningful methods: `if (now().isAfter(expiration))`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: `isAfter` doesn't represent `>=`, it represents `>`.  You could work around that, e.g. with `!isBefore` or `|| equals`, but at a certain point it's simpler to just use `compareTo`.

Comment: I always found calls to `compareTo()` cryptic to read. My taste is certainly with @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- even when it involves `!isBefore` (just slightly difficult but short and simpler than `compareTo`) or `|| equals` (longer but very clear). Admitted, it’s a matter of taste.

Comment: Also, who cares about the last nanosecond? The call to `now()` takes longer than a nanosecond anyway, so what sense does it make to distinguish between `>=` and `>` in this particular situation?

Comment: flawless answer Louis!

Answer (score 11):

*Posting [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391629/how-to-compare-two-instants-in-java#comment117374100_66391665) by [**chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic) as an answer to highlight*

---

`Instant` also has more semantically meaningful methods `isAfter` and `isBefore`

```
if (now().isAfter(expiration)) {
  .. do something ..
}
```

---

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391629/how-to-compare-two-instants-in-java#comment117375310_66391665) by [**@Louis Wasserman**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman)
**

- Note that `isAfter` doesn't represent `>=`, it represents `>`
- You could work around that, e.g. with `!isBefore` or `|| equals`

Answer (score 0):

Following the implementation of compareTo method of Instant class:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Instant otherInstant) {
    int cmp = Long.compare(seconds, otherInstant.seconds);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    return nanos - otherInstant.nanos;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since the title reads "How to compare two instants in Java?" if someone is looking to check the equality of two instants then you can use "equals" method provided by Instant class.

```
void solve() {
      Instant i1 = Instant.parse("2022-08-12T16:10:35.00Z");
      Instant i2 = Instant.parse("2022-08-12T16:10:35.00Z");
      System.out.println("Instant object i1 is: " + i1);
      System.out.println("Instant object i2 is: " + i2);
      if(i1.equals(i2))
         System.out.println("The Instant objects are equal");
      else
         System.out.println("The Instant objects are not equal");
   }
```

As discussed in other answers we could also use isAfter, isBefore, compareTo methods as well.